# Getting function names programmatically

Tags: c, build, cmake

I'm making a build that uses a lot of function pointers, with a `struct` that vaguely looks like this:

```
struct functionArray {
    void (*func)(void);
} funcarray[20] = {
    func1,
    func2,
    func3,
    func4
};
```

Where `func1`, `func2`, ... and `func20` are in a file called functions.c

I want to be able to do this during the build. For example, if I used a macro instead:

```
funcarray[20] = {
    FUNCTION_LIST
};
```

I may be able to do this with a generated header file. Sort of like:

```
// testheader.h.in
#define FUNCTION_LIST @functions_in_file@
```

Is there anyway I can do this? I know I could just go back and forth editing files, but I this is the second or third time I've encourted this. I looked through the [cmake reference][1] and didn't see anything that struck out to me. Could I somehow using `objdump` or `nm` to pipe the function names to a `cmake` file?

Edit:

Getting the function names from the `.o` file should work, too. I guess there's no reason for it to be a `.c` file.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do ? Create the "FUNCTION_LIST" automatically from `functions.c` ? In this case you need something, which is able to at least understand what a (simple) function definition in C looks like, so basically something which is good at text processing (like perl or awk). I do not believe cmake is suitable for this job. Note: This might become **extremely** hard if your `functions.c` file starts to do real funny stuff (like for example defining functions which return a pointer to another functions); because then you need a full fledged C parser.

Comment: yeah, probably not with cmake directly. It doesn't necessarily have to be .c files. Instead it can be .o files. I think all I would need is a program that can display the function names, like `nm`, but without all the additional text

Comment: Hmm what about this `nm functions.o | awk '/[0-9a-f]+ T / { print $3 }'`

Comment: Is that suppose to be on a shell? I tried that and it hangs

Comment: Yeah, I did run this from a shell.

Comment: Oh: Here is a refinement: `nm functions.o | awk '/[0-9a-f]+ T / { print $3 "," }' > function_list.h` . This should put the list of functions into a file called `function_list.h` and then you could just do `} funcarray[20] = { #include "function_list.h" }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here is one way to do it. Generate the object file `functions.o` and then use

```
nm functions.o | awk '/[0-9a-f]+ T / { print $3 "," }' > function_list.h
```

With the code like this

```
struct functionArray {
    void (*func)(void);
} funcarray[20] = {
#include "function_list.h"
};
```

You should be able to then integrate that. Note though that the number of functions in "functions.o" needs to be exactly 20 here.

Comment: thanks. honestly though, I probably wont use your answer exactly as is. Instead of redirecting the output, I'll just capture it in CMake and add it to a header from there

Comment: Sounds even better! I was just browsing through the CMake manual, but still have not much of an idea what features there are.

Comment: It doesn't have to be 20; it must not be more than 20, though.